# Elasticsearch QueryStrings: partially match a NOT query?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I'm making a search field that will use boolean operators ([as described here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_boolean_operators)), and I want them to behave the same as my normal (non-boolean operator) queries, which match on partial strings due to `prefix_match`. To illustrate: search for `fir`, get results like `fire pit`, `fire ball`, `firm`, etc. However, if I then search for `fire -b`, it still returns `fire ball`, which I consider to be wrong; I have to search for `fire -ball` to exclude `fire ball`. Is there a way to change this behaviour?

For reference, this is the query sent to the ES server currently:

```js
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "queryString": {
            "fields": [
              "name"
            ],
            "query": "fire -b",
            "defaultOperator": "OR"
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "fire -b",
            "type": "phrase_prefix",
            "fields": [
              "name"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Query String` query allows wildcards. I believe you should remove the multimatch. I believe messes up your results and just add a wildcard at the end of every term like below. If you want exact matches for some, just don't add the wildcard. Moreover this query supports `fuzziness` which by default is set to `AUTO` which again could mess up your results. If you want to disable it just set it to zero.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "queryString": {
            "fields": [
              "name"
            ],
            "query": "fire* -b*",
            "defaultOperator": "OR"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm going for, since in a default situation I'd like the person to be able to type `fir` and get `fire` and other words similar. However, your answer of adding `*` to the query works, so I think I can work with `fire -b*` being an acceptable query. Therefore I'll keep the prefix matching, but the `*` solves the issue specifically for the NOT clause.

Comment: You can add a wildcard in both terms. So for the `fir` example the query is: `"query": "fir*"`

Comment: I have an additional question. I have a query like this: `"blue wizard" NOT fire`, with prefix matching. I have a few results that have the text `blue wizards` that show up when I search `"blue wizard"` but that disappear when I add the `NOT fire` part; it's as if the NOT query is erasing the partial matching. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Can you open a new topic where you post the exact query you send to elasticsearch and the mapping of your index? You can post the link to the new question here so I get a notification.

Comment: Posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40168826/elasticsearch-prefix-matching-disappears-with-not-added-querystring