# Elasticsearch prefix matching disappears with NOT added (QueryString)

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

Carried over from [Elasticsearch QueryStrings: partially match a NOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40100006/elasticsearch-querystrings-partially-match-a-not-query).

I determined that I couldn't partially match a NOT query, but I still wish to partially match a precedent not-NOT query. For example, I have a query like this: `"blue wizard" NOT fire`, with prefix matching. I have a few results that have the text `blue wizards` that show up when I search `"blue wizard"` but that disappear when I add the `NOT fire` part; it's as if the NOT query is erasing the partial matching.

This is the resulting query sent to ES:

```js
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "queryString": {
            "fields": [
              "reminderlessText"
            ],
            "query": "\"blue wizard\" NOT fire",
            "defaultOperator": "OR"
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "\"blue wizard\" NOT fire",
            "type": "phrase_prefix",
            "fields": [
              "reminderlessText"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you make your test query more complicated by combining the query_string and multi_match in one query?

Looking at it separately:
Your query_string sub-query doesn't say anything about prefixes, so it obviously doesn't match "blue wizards" (except you use a stemming or lemmatization filter, see below.)

Your multi_match sub-query ist of type "phrase_prefix", but in a (multi_)match query you cannot use operators like NOT.
This query resolves to: give me all docs that contain

- blue wizzard  (not sure what will happen to the quotes, depends on your analyzer)
- followed by the word NOT
- followed by something starting with fire

This is obviously not what you want.

I guess your actual problem is: "People searching for 'wizard' should also find docs where the plural 'wizards' appears".
In that case, you want to dive into the topic of stemming.
This might be a good starting point:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/choosing-a-stemmer.html or http://www.intrafind.de/blog/the-difference-between-stemming-and-lemmatization-en

Comment: The reason why I combine `query_string` and `multi_match` is because I wanted the capabilities I state in the OP; being able to use partial matching (search for `wiz`, get `wizard`) as well as being able to use NOT in the same query. I want to search for more than just plurals, I want prefix matching, so I'm not sure if stemming is what I'm looking for.